# Why is closeness of an ideal useful?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, ideals, c-star-algebras

In the GNS-construction for an $C^*$-algebra $\mathcal A$ (see [this script on page 30](http://www.math.lmu.de/~michel/SS13_MSP-Script_mathematical_part.pdf)) one starts with a state $\phi:\mathcal A\rightarrow \mathbb C$ (positive linear functional with $\|\phi\|=1$). Take $N_\phi = \{A\in\mathcal A:\phi(A^*A)=0\}$ and show, that $N_\phi$ is a closed left ideal of $\mathcal A$. Then one continues using the completion of $\mathcal A/N_\phi$ with the inner product $\langle A,B\rangle=\phi(A^*B)$ (this completion shall be an Hilbert space).

I understand, that $N_\phi$ must be an ideal. So $\mathcal A/N_\phi$ is still an algebra. But it is necessary that $N_\phi$ is closed? If $N_\phi$ wouldn't be closed, can $\mathcal A/N_\phi$ still be a pre-Hilbert space? Which property of $\mathcal A/N_\phi$ needs the closeness of $N_\phi$?

Comment: Hausdorff. A quotient $E/F$ of topological vector spaces is Hausdorff iff $F$ is closed.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for your quick reply. Please write a short answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closedness of an ideal (or more generally subspace) is useful because it makes the quotient space Hausdorff. A topological vector space is Hausdorff if and only if $\{0\}$ is closed (by translation invariance of the topology, that means the space is $T_1$, and since it's a uniform space, that implies Hausdorff), and that means a quotient space $E/F$ is Hausdorff if and only if $F$ is closed.

Since non-Hausdorff topological vector spaces are often inconvenient, in situations where such would arise, one usually considers the associated Hausdorff TVS $E/\overline{\{0\}}$.

In the given situation, $N_\phi$ is closed because it is the level set of a continuous function ($A \mapsto \phi(A^\ast A)$) to a Hausdorff space ($\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: I am probably severely misunderstanding something, but $\mathcal{A}/N_\phi$ has no topology bestowed upon it in the beginning. Then we define an inner product on it, which is well defined, since $N_\phi$ is a left ideal, and which now induces a topology onto $\mathcal{A}/N_\phi$. So $\mathcal{A}/N_\phi$ is a pre-Hilbert space. I don't quite see where closedness plays a role.

Comment: @h3fr43nd If we define an arbitrary topology on the quotient, closedness plays no role. But generally we are interested in the quotient topology, or at least in topologies coarser than the quotient topology (thus the quotient map is continuous), and then closedness plays a role because we like Hausdorff topologies.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I was just wondering, since I was looking at the proof of the GNS construction and I didn't see why all the authors mentioned, that $N_\phi$ is a $\textbf{closed}$ left ideal. Because for the GNS-construction only the property of being a left ideal is relevant as far as i understood.